# How do brand laptop manufacturers restrict hard disk drive?

Tags: laptop, bios, system-reserved-partition

I'm curious to know, when I bought a brand new laptop there are limitations to create or change the HDD partitions, except the following partitions:

```
c:\ drive (Main partition + OS drive) NTFS. 400 Gb.
Recovery drive NTFS. 15 Gb.
Tools drive FAT32. 2 Gb.
System drive NTFS. 0.3 Gb.
```

My questions are:

1. How do manufacturers restrict HDDs ?
2. What is the term for these restrictions?
3. Can this be applied to desktop PCs?
4. Is it possible to modify the restrictions by an end-user?

Comment: They don't actually restrict anything.  Its not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Your harddrive probably has a MBR partition table, which means it's limited to 4 physical partitions. I imagine when they configured the drive, they set up all four partitions as physical partitions, which prevents any more from being created until at least one is removed.

Normally, an MBR harddrive will be set up with 3 physical partitions, and then a special 4th partition which contains logical partitions. This allows more than 4 partitions to be put on a single disk.